# The webpage cannot be found only for certain users. aspx intranet page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

hi I have an intranet page which just shows some graphs and table data but some users are reporting get the following:

[image: error image]

I have checked the link the users are using and it is identical to the 1 myself and several others users are using. I've also made sure we are on the exact same network and the page contains no authentication.

Please any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It may be an network error, DNS related

Comment: You need to check 1) if it's not because of cache 2) if user receives same response when starting IE under different account 3) if IE has same settings (e.g. Intranet Zone, integrated windows authentication, etc) 4) if you have any requests logged in IIS log file or event viewer on server 5) if user receives same response in other browser (if he has different browsers installed)